# Simple pysFTP was working last night, but now does not

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks, pysftp

Last night I was writing my first pySFTP Notebook, and I was able to get it to work. It was working when I went to bed, but now it does not. I get an error on the connection command....

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None    # disable host key checking.
#with pysftp.Connection('test.rebex.net', username='demo',password='password', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
# do stuff here
#  print('this works!')


s = pysftp.Connection(host='test.rebex.net', username='demo', password='password', cnopts=cnopts) 
data = s.listdir() 
s.close() 
for i in data: 
    print (i)
```

The error I am receiving is...

```
Unknown exception: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a bytes or unicode object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2075, in run
    self.kex_engine.parse_next(ptype, m)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/kex_curve25519.py", line 64, in parse_next
    return self._parse_kexecdh_reply(m)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/kex_curve25519.py", line 129, in _parse_kexecdh_reply
    self.transport._activate_outbound()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2553, in _activate_outbound
    self.local_cipher, key_out, IV_out, self._ENCRYPT
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1934, in _get_cipher
    return cipher.encryptor()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py", line 121, in encryptor
    self.algorithm, self.mode
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 298, in create_symmetric_encryption_ctx
    return _CipherContext(self, cipher, mode, _CipherContext._ENCRYPT)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py", line 67, in __init__
    iv_nonce = self._backend._ffi.from_buffer(mode.nonce)
TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a bytes or unicode object

TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a bytes or unicode object
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This error seems to be happening intermittently/inconsistently. I have the script scheduled as a job, and sometimes it works while sometimes it does not- irrespective of files being available.

Comment: Also, I needed to be more specific about which pysftp libraru was being loaded into my cluster. I specified pysftp==0.2.9. That didn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pysftp` lists `paramiko` as [one of its dependencies](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/default/requirements-dev.txt). [Paramiko issue #1037](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1027) documents and attributes the error thrown in your code to a version compatibility issue with `cryptography`.

My recommendations to avoid this include the following:

1. Use the [Databricks Conda Runtime](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/clusters/conda.html) for improved Python dependency management and visibility
2. Upgrade the cryptography version (I tested with `cryptography=2.6.1`, which is included in the `databricks-standard` conda env)

Comment: This is working great! Thanks, Myles! I really appreciate your help.